# BndTools perspective is missing from eclipse 2018-09 MacOS

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-2018-09

I have installed the BndTools plugin from the marketplace in a fresh eclipse download.

In the beginning, everything was fine. After a reset, the perspective seems to be missing and the right menu options are also missing:

[image]

[image]

I have installed DevTools also, but in the past this was not a problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was the fact that misconfiguration of one of the plugins. The use of jgit version > 5.0.0 was needed but eclipse was using a version < 5.0.0. By updating jgit the issue was resolved.